# .Net 4.0 WebApp deployment picking latest GAC version of dlls instead in bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, office-interop, gac

Working environment
1. Windows 10
2. Visual Studio 2010
3. .Net 4.0
4. Outlook 2013
5. Dll Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook version showed in pic below

Yes this is my question that I have added Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook to access Outlook mail. Working fine at development environment. But when I publish it on a virtual machine, and user press button to use Outlook feature, it crashes with error message shown in the picture below

I checked that this is the exact version defined in my GAC while I am using version 14 in my development and its coming from this folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14

I spent 2 full days on it and cannot solve. Please help me to fix either my GAC or use the correct version of Interop dlls I am using in project.
How to get/use ver. 15 dlls in my project.

Here are the pictures
[image]

[image: Dll version I am using in WebSite]

Thanks

QZ

Comment: the GAC always wins...

Comment: This is my question how to solve it. Either GAC reflect the version of dlls I am using or from where I can get those version 15 dlls to use in my project to remove the conflict. I am stuck at this point.